# What is the maximum current the Raspberry PI zero 2 w will draw?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm designing a device to use this PI and need to know how much current to allocate for it. It will only be driving a single HDMI monitor, using a UART, and a hat board driven from the OTG USB.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [raspberrypi.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: Is there a way to move the post there or do I just need to repost it there?

Comment: There's no migration path to that site, unless you want to wait and hope that a diamond moderator sees it and decides to move it. I'd suggest you just delete it here and ask there instead; you can copy/paste the one paragraph of text from the post body, and just have to type the title and add a tag at the other site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming and probably belongs on the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange site.